# too many arguments while calculating values

Tags: javascript

I have multiple variables that use arguments to calculate an answer, but it only seems to work when I have a single variable with arguments.

My HTML is:

```
<textarea id="given" placeholder="Given"></textarea>
            <input type="text" id="result" placeholder="Result" list="resultAutoComplete"/>
                <datalist id="resultAutoComplete">
                    <option value="v">(v) Speed</option>
                    <option value="ρ">(ρ) density</option>
                    <option value="Eₚ">(Eₚ) Potential energy</option>
                </datalist>

            <button type="button" onClick="calculateAnswer();">result</button>
            <p><a id="Rho" onClick="RhoAdd();" style="cursor: pointer;">ρ</a></p>
            <button id="Example" onClick="Examplefill();" style="cursor: pointer;">ρ</button>

        <p>Answer: <b id="answer"></b></p>
        <div style="background-color: #ACACAC; width: 100%;"><ins style="color: #ED141A; font-size: 20px; margin-left: 5px;" id="errorAlerts"></ins></div>
```

When I get rid of other variables: **ress** and **rest** it works.

Here's what worked

```
function calculateAnswer() {
   var givenInput = document.getElementById('given').value;
   var road_s = givenInput.match(/s=(.*)(;)/);                               //looks for S= (road)
   var time_t = givenInput.match(/t=(.*)(;)/);                               //looks for t= (time)
   var speed_v = givenInput.match(/v=(.*)(;)/);                           //looks for v= (speed)

   var toFind = document.getElementById('result').value;

   var resv = road_s[1] / time_t[1];

    if (toFind === "v") {
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = resv;
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "ERROR... invalid requested result";
    }
}
```

I need this to print out a answer using road_s[1], time_t[1] and speed_v[1], but when I add more variables using these arguments

```
var resv = road_s[1] / time_t[1];
var ress = speed_v[1] * time_t[1];
var rest = road_s[1] / speed_v[1];
```

the system doesn't print out anything

```
function calculateAnswer() {
    var givenInput = document.getElementById('given').value;
    var road_s = givenInput.match(/s=(.*)(;)/);                               //looks for S= (road)
    var time_t = givenInput.match(/t=(.*)(;)/);                               //looks for t= (time)
    var speed_v = givenInput.match(/v=(.*)(;)/);                              //looks for v= (speed)

    var toFind = document.getElementById('result').value;

    var resv = road_s[1] / time_t[1];
    var ress = speed_v[1] * time_t[1];
    var rest = road_s[1] / speed_v[1];

    if (toFind === "v") {
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = resv;
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "ERROR... invalid requested result";
    }
    if (toFind === "s") {
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = ress;
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "ERROR... invalid requested result";
    }
    if (toFind === "t") {
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = rest;
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "ERROR... invalid requested result";
    }
}
```

It's is very hard to explain because I'm not very familiar with arguments.

Comment: It's difficult to know what the problem is from looking at that. Can you provide a working example with your HTML so we can test it?

Comment: there, I edited the post with my HTML

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a blank comment describing 99% of all pieces of software under development as we speak. Could you elaborate on that? What is the expected result and what "doesn't work"?

Comment: Took your code and built a repl, https://repl.it/@TobiasParent/tooManyArgsSO - now I just need to know what your input would look like.

Comment: I've also added your code into two snippets so it's waiting to be reviewed and made visible, so just don't edit the post until then or it'll be wiped. Like Snowmoney said, can you explain what you have to input?

Comment: Dammit you did it anyway.

Comment: You have input  t=12;inthe first line and s=2; in the second

Comment: and in Result you need to type in v

Comment: Those are not arguments.. they are variables. First you have to understand the basics to have a conversation in the first place.

Comment: Well, one issue you're encountering is, two of those three calculations will quietly fail. And at the first one to fail, all execution is halted. When you specify the three equations, you need to be able to handle when one of the three variables doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm talking about only about time_t[1], not the whole variable StackSlave

Comment: posted a possible, though hacky, solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: Where can I learn about "null", because as much as I've learned javascript, they don't get that indepth with it. So that I can understand better why your solution worked Snowmonkey.

Comment: https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/null -- of specific interest in there is this line: `null expresses a lack of identification, indicating that a variable points to no object.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are a few things going on here. First, when you `match` your regex (given the input you've commented), you will always have one of the three that doesn't match. Given the comment input, `speed_v` will be `null`, and would cause a fatal error in two of the three equations. At the first fatal error, the program would halt.

To fix this, I changed your match statements a little:

```
var road_s = givenInput.match(/s=(.*)(;)/) || [null, 0];   //looks for S= (road)
var time_t = givenInput.match(/t=(.*)(;)/) || [null, 0];   //looks for t= (time)
var speed_v = givenInput.match(/v=(.*)(;)/) || [null, 0];  //looks for v= (speed)
```

In each case, if match returns null, the `||` operator (logical or) kicks in, and creates a 'dummy array', containing `[null, 0]` - thus providing a value for the missing option, each time.

The second problem you encounter is in your `if` statement. In each branch, you say 'if the chosen option is thus-and-such, display the calculation. if not, show an error!' And that is happening for each of the various options.

A better approach may be to use a `switch` statement, allowing you to watch for each possible outcome:

```
    switch(toFind){
      case 'v':
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = resv;
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "";
        break;
      case 's':
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = ress;
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "";
        break;
      case 't':
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = rest;
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "";
        break;
      default:
        document.getElementById('errorAlerts').innerHTML = "ERROR... invalid requested result";
    }
```

To see this as a working solution, take a look at this repl: https://repl.it/@TobiasParent/tooManyArgsSO

**edit:** I know this is a hacky solution, but let's face it - the HTML is hacky, the input is hacky, the whole thing has a slap-dash feel. Given that, this is a teachable moment. Learn about the switch/case branching mechanism, and try to understand **why** you were getting a fatal error in your calculations.

Comment: Now when I input "s" or "t" into Result it prints out "NaN" or "Infinity"

Comment: Well, sure - you're doing three calculations, two with a zero in. One will always result in zero, the other in infinity. An interesting twist you **could** do - if the user inputs `s=12;t=47;`, you could simply not calculate the unrelated ones. have a 'smart calculation' happen.

Comment: Quickest fix to that, I suppose, would be to have the default array be `[null, 1]` instead of `[null, 0]` - then you avoid division by zero errors. Still, the result would be not what you expect. It might be wise to refer back to your original spec, and see if you can figure a way to redesign the interface to support what you're actually trying to build.